# Can US citizen transit in Schiphol enroute to UK? (two questions)

Tags: usa, uk, covid-19

1. My US wife obtained spouse visa for UK however flights to Manchester, UK from Detroit seem to transit in Amsterdam. Can my US wife transit Amsterdam enroute to UK? Information on US.gov seems to just say transit through Amsterdam is allowed if final destination is outside the EU, and it's up to the Dutch authorities to decide to allow onward travel to UK.
2. We found another flight from Detroit to Heathrow with a stop in JFK. If my wife lands in Heathrow, I could drive down and pick her up however it's a 4-5 hour drive from Liverpool. Would this cause issues at the border for her - the fact she is going to self-isolate in a location 250 miles away? We are not making any stops however I do think Border Force would take issue with this.

Finally, if anybody has made the journey recently from the States to the UK could you please give some advice on how you did it and where your layover was, and if you had any issues. We used to regularly fly Detroit to Manchester with a stop in JFK or Philadelphia however no flights with this route seem to be available.

Thanks.

Comment: For the price you're proposing to pay for these flights you can probably get a flight from DTW-***-LHR-MAN, where *** is some airport between DTW and LHR. Search [ITA Matrix](http://matrix.itasoftware.com/) with advanced routing code `X? LHR` to find such flights. At the moment MAN doesn't seem to have any direct flights to/from the USA though there may be some in October.

Comment: I appreciate the comment but money isn't an issue. We are leaning towards option 2. I just want to know if travelling via car from London to Liverpool will pose an issue with the self-isolation rules. Will Border Force dislike her self isolation destination is 200 miles away? Do you think she'll have a hard time?

Comment: AFAIK that's not a problem. I think we've had a couple of similar questions already. And I'm not suggesting that money is an issue, just that for a similar amount of money you might possibly find it more convenient to fly into MAN even with a stop at LHR.

Comment: Oh ok, this is great. Do you perhaps have any links to the similar questions? Apologies, I only did a quick search but was eager to ask myself, so sorry if you've received lots of these questions lately.

Comment: I took a quick look at some of the recent questions but I didn't see one right away. Another reader might spot it before I do.

Comment: As two questions in one does not work well here and your second option seems to be the most important part of this question, why not edit it out here and ask as a new question or edit option one to an aftertought and also edit the header.

Comment: @Willeke Thank you. I'll do this in the future but I'm satisfied my main concerns have been answered now. Thanks all!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can my US wife transit Amsterdam enroute to UK?

Even if she could today, rules are changing constantly as infection rates wax and wane.  The fewer countries she has to deal with, the less uncertain and stressful the trip will be.  A direct flight from the US to the UK would clearly be best in that light.

> Would this cause issues at the border for her - the fact she is going to self-isolate in a location 250 miles away?

Unlikely.  Making the trip in a car rather than on another commercial flight or a train is certainly certainly safer for her and for the public health.  In light of the lack of direct flights between the US and Manchester this seems the best option.

Comment: Thank you very much. We opted to book flights from JFK to LHR as, as you say, rules are constantly changing and it may not be possible to transit through Amsterdam in the future. We've decided it's best flying through LHR as we can then travel to our accommodation without interacting with other people. Many thanks.